# Don't prevent me from undoing a vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, voting, down-votes

I recently downvoted an answer because it seemed totally irrelevant to the question at hand. When I checked back a short time later, a comment had clarified that the answer was, indeed, a good one. When I tried to retract my vote, I got this error:

```
You last voted on this answer 
20 mins ago 
Your vote is now locked in 
unless this answer is edited
```

I understand (as per a few other questions on this site) that this is by design, and is in place to prevent users from "gaming the system." I appreciate this, but I feel that it would be better to allow votes to be undone an unlimited time after posting. To avoid "tactical voting," the user could lose voting privileges for that question after a vote had been undone,  or perhaps lose another reputation point. Thoughts? I feel bad for penalizing somebody because of my limited understanding.

Comment: Tactical voters wouldn't care about voting again among other answers if they're going to remove a vote. Also taking rep away for what is essentially doing nothing is going to not be easily understood

Comment: @random fair enough. I was misunderstanding how people would use "tactical voting."

Comment: Do you have more than 2k rep? If so, you can make a minor edit (remove signiatures, etc), then remove your vote.

Answer (score 7):

The question is, did the comment add context and information to the question, therefore completing it? Or was the comment a "Nice one this w0rkz!!" from someone you can "trust"?

If it was the former then the down vote was deserved as the answer was theoretically incomplete. If the relevant bits from the comment are edited back into the answer then you can reverse your vote (because it has been edited). Where possible this editing should be done, as useful content should not live in comments.

If it was the latter then arguably the down vote should stand because it wasn't clear enough for you to understand the answer. If you still feel bad about the down vote then you might need to tame your itchy clicky finger so that you don't rush into voting too quickly in the future.

As most old timers around here know, you can effect a nothing (null, inconsequential) edit to the answer in order to be able to reverse your down vote, but personally I would not advocate doing this unless your voting transgression was truly egregious - if everyone starts doing this we will see a whole bunch of spurious edits simply to work around this deliberate limitation.

Comment: Arguably, the connection would have been made by someone with more knowledge of the subject, but it wasn't clear to me. For context, the answer  quickly got a few more downvotes after mine, then quickly shot up to +2.

Comment: @rogaos if you weren't sure enough that it definitely wasn't an answer to the question, you shouldn't have down-voted.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was pretty damn sure. See the first version of http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18243540/revisions. thanks for your answer!

Comment: @rogaos see, I don't have enough knowledge of the subject to even understand what you're trying to illustrate. So I would certainly not have down-voted without that knowledge. I'm just trying to explain in general terms that you should avoid casting down-votes unless you have enough knowledge of the subject to be certain that the answer is a bad one. And I am intentionally using your words so that it is clear that "knowledge of the subject" is important.