# Allow late (past a lock period) downvote reversals without reputation credit

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

The topic itself has been [widely discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/vote-reversal-time-limit-concerns?rq=1) and it seems that [a solution I like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75508/213957) has been broached [more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/dont-prevent-me-from-undoing-a-vote).  I'm not sure what is the current prevailing opinion, though.

Let's rehash a possible scenario.  I downvoted an answer that seems to be wrong and posted my own one.  Later, after my downvote was already locked, I realized that I read that question wrong and it didn't deserve a downvote.  At such time I can either leave *unjust* downvote there or do an unneeded edit just to allow myself to undo my downvote.

My initial actions could be construed as [tactical downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem) and, from what I understand, the lock is specifically preventing such behavior by not allowing downvoters to reclaim their lost reputation points.

The bottom line here is that a person (for whatever reason) regrets his/her downvote and wants to do something about it.

So, what about a suggestion to allow *late* downvote removals without crediting back the rep.  This logic is similar to bounty handling.

Is it worth a consideration or are we better off with a trivial edit just to circumvent the lock?

Comment: You misread the answer. Are you sure that could happen to no one else? Maybe a little clarifying edit wouldn't be such a bad thing here...

Comment: @Shog9 - Is it better now?  The main point is that it's immaterial what exactly caused a *wrong* downvote.  All we know is that a downvoter regrets it and wants to make it right.

Comment: @random - As I stated this suggestion is not new.  Neither the question you declared as duplicate nor the ones I linked to provide any answers in favor or against it.  So, **no**, this question does **not** *have an answer*.

Comment: Having an answer you disagree with doesn't make it less a duplicate

Comment: @random Are you saying that [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153003/retract-post-lock-votes-at-rep-cost-without-erasing-history) actually has an answer?  If so, would you be so kind to quote it?

Comment: Yes. The answer is "No"