# (Undoing or) Confirming downvotes (and upvotes ?)

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, user-interface, up-votes

Occasionally, I will check my **smartphone** for possible news from SE. I
noticed that, while **scrolling with my finger**, I will occasionally push
a button without noticing, and I end up in particular downvoting users
without meaning to do so.

When I find out, it is usually too late to undo it. And my only
awkward solution is to apologize in a comment and ask the author of
the post to edit so that I can undo.  This helps in no way the quality
of the site.

I would be equally annoyed if I accidentally upvoted a post that is
clearly wrong. But then, there is nothing I can do, other than hope
for an edit.

So I consider it would be better to be allowed to undo votes without a
time limit (I may take some days for me to notice). But I realize that people have been asking that for eons, and will probably have to wait till the next Big-Bang.

A possible and probably **better suggestion** would be to have the
**option to tell the system that it should ask user confirmation** for
downvotes and upvotes on posts. This would leave unchange the tactical
voting issues, whatever they are.

When I have enough rep, I can of course do a minor edit, but this is
not available to everyone, and is far from a clean solution. It feels very much like abusing a privilege.

**Related posts:**

- [Don't prevent me from undoing a vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/dont-prevent-me-from-undoing-a-vote)

  This is about intentional votes, that the users would have
  confirmed. It can call for different solutions than correcting
  unintended votes.
- [Undoing an old vote cannot be recast because vote is too ol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old)d

  Same issue: several examples are intentional votes. Furthermore [Jeff
  Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old/48323#48323) does not do anything for accidental mistakes.
- [Vote Reversal Time Limit Concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18788/vote-reversal-time-limit-concerns)

  Idem

*Post-Scriptum: (this is a side-note related to the writing of the question) I looked for a tag corresponding to hardware related problems,
but the best I could do was [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface). The tag [hardware](/questions/tagged/hardware) look pretty much like its name: a junk box of questions.*

Comment: This is supposed to be a contribution to improve the system in some uses, without changing anything for whoever is not interested. You may see fauts with this proposal. Then please make it explicit.